# How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property

Tags: json, string, array, parsing

I have an incoming JSON payload that with the parameter `device_config`. This parameter might be, at times, sent as an array of strings or a string. How would I handle this parameter when its being sent

```
  {
    "device": [
      "1337966815",
      "6815133796",
      "3796136815",
    ]
    "device_config": [
      "sensor a",
      "sensor b",
      "sensor c",
      "sensor d",
      "sensor e"
    ]
  },
  {
    "device": [
      "9337966001",
      "7815133002",
      "8796136003",
    ]
    "device_config": ""
  }
```

Comment: Is this a general json question or are you processing the data within Salesforce?

Comment: @FlorianHeer I am processing the data within Salesforce